# Regex, extract date from a file name

Tags: c#, regex

Sample text is:

```cs
Statement_10125229_20170807.pdf
```

I would like to get the date, **20170807**.

I was able to extract the statement ID using `(?<=_).*?(?=_)` = 10125229.
Now I would like to extract the date, I have tried `(?<=_)\d*` but I am still getting back also the Statement ID.

Comment: Try `(?<=_)\d+(?=\.)`, or something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/wazhtO/1) (`(?<=_)[^_]*(?=\.pdf)`).

Comment: Apart from regular expressions, you might very well simply split it. Please also add your programming language (if any).

Comment: If the date is always 8 digits, and using a capture group `_(\d{8})\.pdf` or a very broad match `\B\d{8}\b` that does not take the underscores into account.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried your answer and I was able to get the date. (Jan) the lang will be C#. (The Fourth bird) the very broad match also works.

Answer (score 1):

In general, `(?<=_)\d+(?=\.)` and `(?<=_)[^_]*(?=\.pdf)` [would solve](https://regex101.com/r/wazhtO/1) your issue. The `(?<=_)\d+(?=\.)` pattern matches one or more digits that are immediately preceded with a `_` and immediately followed with `.`. The `(?<=_)[^_]*(?=\.pdf)` pattern matches any zero or more chars other than `_` that are immediately preceded with a `_` and immediately followed with `.pdf`.

However, in C#, you can actually get the substring you need without a regex. You can use

```cs
var text = "Statement_10125229_20170807.pdf";
var result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(text).Split('_').LastOrDefault();
```

With a regex, you can also go for a capturing approach:

```
var result = Regex.Match(text, @"_(\d+)\.pdf$")?.Groups[1].Value;
```

See the [C# demo online](https://ideone.com/3t3SKn), both approaches yield `20170807`.